# In Attempt to Create a JFileChooser--public variables?

Tags: java, swing, jfilechooser

In my previous question, I've stated I'm somewhat new to Java's JFrame features.
I'm trying to create a JFileChooser that will get a directory in which a file named `setup.exe` will be saved. That's irrelevant, though.
I'm receiving this error:

```
C:\Users\b\Downloads\files\thankyousanta>javac UpdateMechanism.java
UpdateMechanism.java:31: error: <identifier> expected
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                               ^
UpdateMechanism.java:31: error: <identifier> expected
        fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                                                             ^
UpdateMechanism.java:33: error: <identifier> expected
        openButton.addActionListener(openButton);
                                    ^
UpdateMechanism.java:33: error: <identifier> expected
        openButton.addActionListener(openButton);
                                               ^
4 errors
```

...for this code:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontFormatException;
import java.awt.GraphicsEnvironment;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner; 

import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.Swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class definitiveVoid extends JFileChooser implements ActionListener {
    JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
    fc.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
    JButton openButton = new JButton("The update is waiting on you.");
    openButton.addActionListener(openButton);
}
public class UpdateMechanism extends JPanel
                                implements ActionListener {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == openButton) {
            int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(UpdateMechanism.this);
            if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

            } else {
                // operation cancelled
            }
        } else {
            // destroy life
        }
    }
    private static String readURL(String targetURL) {
        String returnish = "";
        try {
            URL tempURL = new URL(targetURL); 
            Scanner s = new Scanner(tempURL.openStream()); 
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                returnish = returnish+s.nextLine(); 
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e); 
        }
        return returnish;
    }

    private static String readFile(String targetFile) { 
        String returnString = "";
        try {
            File tempFile = new File(targetFile);
            Scanner s = new Scanner(tempFile);
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                returnString = returnString + s.nextLine(); 
            }
        } catch(IOException e) { 
            // !
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        return returnString;
    }

    private static void showGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("The Neverhood Restoration Project");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(1024, 600));
        frame.setExtendedState(frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0xA64343));

        File fileCheck = new File("C:/Program Files (x86)");
        String returnString = null;
        String rootDirectory = null;
        if (fileCheck.exists()) {
            rootDirectory = "C:/Program Files (x86)/DreamWorks Interactive"; 
            String checkFile = rootDirectory+"/Neverhood/version.txt"; 
            File tempFile = new File(checkFile);
            if (tempFile.exists()) {
                returnString = readFile(checkFile);
            } else {
                returnString = "It appears you do not have the Neverhood Restoration Project installed, or you are using an earlier version."; 
            }
        } else {
            rootDirectory = "C:/Program Files/DreamWorks Interactive";
            String checkFile = rootDirectory+"/Neverhood/version.txt"; 
            File tempFile = new File(checkFile);
            if (tempFile.exists()) {
                returnString = readFile(checkFile);
            } else {
                returnString = "It appears you do not have the Neverhood Restoration Project installed, or you are using an earlier version.";
            }
        }
        if (returnString.equals(readURL("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/version.txt"))) {
            returnString = "You are updated to the recent version!"; 
        } else { 
            returnString = "It appears you're not updated.";
        }

        JLabel headerLabel = new JLabel("The Neverhood Restoration Project");
        headerLabel.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        JPanel heapPanel = new JPanel();
        heapPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(heapPanel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
        heapPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, heapPanel.getPreferredSize().height));
        JTextArea heapLabel = new JTextArea(50, 50);        
        heapLabel.setLineWrap(true);
        heapLabel.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        heapLabel.setEditable(false);
        heapLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 20, 10, 20));
        heapLabel.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        heapLabel.append("Current version: "+readURL("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/prettyversion.txt")+".\nInstalled version: "+readFile(rootDirectory+"/Neverhood/prettyversion.txt")+".\n"+returnString+"\n" + 
            "You can read the full version of the document to the left at http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net."
            + "\nBelow is the download button. Just click, choose your directory to save setup.exe in and enjoy!");
        heapPanel.add(heapLabel);

        try {
            Font sFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("DUGFB___.TTF"));
            sFont = sFont.deriveFont(Font.PLAIN, 48);
            GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
            ge.registerFont(sFont);
            headerLabel.setFont(sFont);
        } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

        BufferedImage icoImage = null;
        try {
            icoImage = ImageIO.read(
                frame.getClass().getResource("/nhood.bmp"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        frame.setIconImage(icoImage);

        JEditorPane updateLog = new JEditorPane();
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(updateLog);
        updateLog.setEditable(false);

        try {
            updateLog.setPage("http://theneverhood.sourceforge.net/");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            updateLog.setContentType("text/html");
            updateLog.setText("<html>The application could not load the webpage.</html>");
        }

        frame.add(headerLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.add(heapPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                showGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Java, public classes must be defined in their own file, having the same name (with a .java suffix) as the class name.

You defined a public class named `definitiveVoid` in the file `UpdateMechanism.java`. And you tried to put code directly in this class, outside of any method. That isn't valid Java.

Swing is hard and complex. Don't try to use it before knowing the basics of Java.

Moreover, classes, by convention, start with an uppercase letter in Java.

Comment: No, because I don't understand anything to what you want to achieve with this class. It doesn't make any sense to me (and to the Java compiler).

Comment: There is no global scope in Java. Stop googling, step back, and start reading an introductory Java book or the Java tutorial explaining classes, objects, variables, arguments and fields. Using Swing without understanding these won't lead you anywhere.

Comment: You don't need a 700-page book to explain that. If you have already read it, re-reading the few first pages of the book or the Java tutorial should be enough.